# Problem with camera preview in C# OpenCVsharp 4.9.0

Tags: c#, .net, windows, opencv, camera

As in title i have problem with camera preview in my code. I am using C# net framework 4.7.2 and opencvsharp 4.9.0
this is form1
if anyone could tell me whats wrong i would be really thankfull
this is only form1 i have also form2 and 3 but i dont think it matters

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;

namespace Fotobudka
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private VideoCapture videoCapture;
        private Button captureButton;
        public PictureBox pictureBoxCaptured;
        private Bitmap lastFrame;
        private bool isCountingDown = false;
        private int slajd = 1;
        private object lockObject = new object();
        private bool cameraStarted = false;
        private Bitmap lastCapturedFrame;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeUI();
            InitializeCamera();

            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox5.Visible = false;
            pictureBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            pictureBox5.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            buttonust.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            buttonust.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            buttonust.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            buttonust.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;

            CenterSlideshow();
        }

        private void VideoCapture_FrameGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var frame = new Mat())
            {
                if (videoCapture.Retrieve(frame))
                {
                    ProcessFrame(frame);
                }
            }
        }

        private void InitializeCamera()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    videoCapture = new VideoCapture(i);

                    if (videoCapture.IsOpened())
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Kamera o indeksie {i} została poprawnie otwarta.");
                        StartCamera();
                        cameraStarted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Nie udało się otworzyć kamery o indeksie {i}.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Błąd inicjalizacji kamery o indeksie {i}: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }

            if (!cameraStarted)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Brak dostępnych kamer USB.");
                videoCapture.Dispose(); // Dispose tylko jeśli nie ma dostępnych kamer
                this.Close();
                return;
            }
        }


        private void StartCamera()
        {
            if (videoCapture.IsOpened())
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (videoCapture.IsOpened())
                    {
                        using (var frame = new Mat())
                        {
                            ProcessFrame(frame);
                        }
                    }
                });

                cameraStarted = true;
            }
        }


        private void StopCamera()
        {
            videoCapture.Dispose();
            cameraStarted = false;
        }


        private void InitializeUI()
        {
            pictureBoxCaptured = new PictureBox();
            pictureBoxCaptured.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 800);
            pictureBoxCaptured.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBoxCaptured);

            captureButton = button1;
            captureButton.Click += CaptureButton_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(captureButton);

            Resize += Form1_Resize;
            buttonust.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            this.Deactivate += Form1_Deactivate;
        }

        private void CenterSlideshow()
        {
            pictureBox1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2 + 700;
            pictureBox1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2;

            pictureBox2.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2 + 700;
            pictureBox2.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2;

            pictureBox3.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2 + 700;
            pictureBox3.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2;

            pictureBox4.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2 + 700;
            pictureBox4.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2;

            pictureBox5.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox5.Width) / 2 + 700;
            pictureBox5.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox5.Height) / 2;
            buttonust.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        private async void CountDownAndCapture()
        {
            CenterSlideshow();

            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
            {
                switch (slajd)
                {
                    case 1:
                        pictureBox5.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pictureBox4.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pictureBox3.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }

                await Task.Delay(1000);

                pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                pictureBox5.Visible = false;

                slajd++;

                CenterSlideshow();
            }

            CaptureAndShowPhoto();

            MessageBox.Show("lastCapturedFrame != null: " + (lastFrame != null));

            isCountingDown = false;

            if (lastFrame != null)
            {
                this.Hide();
                Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
                form2.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
                form2.Show();
                form2.SetImage(lastFrame);
            }
        }

        private void CaptureAndShowPhoto()
        {
            if (lastFrame != null)
            {
                lastCapturedFrame = (Bitmap)lastFrame.Clone();

                if (lastCapturedFrame != null)
                {
                    pictureBoxCaptured.Image = (Bitmap)lastFrame.Clone();

                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        lastFrame.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("lastCapturedFrame is null after cloning.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("lastFrame is null.");
            }
        }


        private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnActivated(e);
            StartCamera();
        }

        private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopCamera();
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CenterControl(pictureBox);
            CenterSlideshow();
            CenterControl(captureButton, 100);
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            buttonust.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        private void CenterControl(Control control, int yOffset = 0)
        {
            control.Left = (ClientSize.Width - control.Width) / 2;
            control.Top = (ClientSize.Height - control.Height - 100) / 2 + yOffset;
            button1.Left = (ClientSize.Width - button1.Width) / 2;
            button1.Top = (ClientSize.Height - button1.Height - 100);
        }

        private void ProcessFrame(Mat frame)
        {
            lastFrame = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
            if (lastFrame != null)
            {
                var bitmapFrame = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);

                if (pictureBox.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    pictureBoxCaptured.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBoxCaptured.Image = bitmapFrame));
                }

                frame.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error converting frame to bitmap.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }



        private async void CaptureButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lastFrame != null && pictureBoxCaptured != null)
            {
                lastCapturedFrame = (Bitmap)lastFrame.Clone();
                pictureBoxCaptured.Image = (Bitmap)lastFrame.Clone();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
            StopCamera();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CountDownAndCapture();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartCamera();
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            CenterControl(pictureBox);
            CenterSlideshow();
            CenterControl(captureButton, 100);
            InitializeCamera();
            buttonust.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        private void buttonust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 form3 = new Form3();
            form3.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

i tried adding logs to my code, but they didnt show much, it seems like pictureboxes are wrongly configured or idk frame processing.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Questions that ask others for debugging help are considered off topic. In order to make the question relevant to the site please convert this to a minimal reproducible example of the problem, and give a more focused title/explanation to the problem. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic